# Running exported Inception on Google ML: Expected float32 got 'str'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I retrained the Inception model using the [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) example and with the --saved_model_dir flag to export the model for serving in the end.

I uploaded the final model to Google ML engine with success and I  am now trying to run predictions from it.

My request looks like this:

```
{"image": {"b64": "/9j/4AAQxh6AP/2Q== ..."}}
```

But I get an error back saying:

```
{"error": "Prediction failed: Error processing input: Expected float32, got '\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0 ...' of type 'str' instead."}
```

Is the export example in retrain.py not exporting the model for use with Google ML Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the exported models is expecting arrays of floats instead of raw image bytes. I traced through the code to confirm this. Specifically, [`export_model`](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/422ac2c400534ef15c0cd289e19abca31e1811a0/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L947) calls [`build_eval_session`](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/422ac2c400534ef15c0cd289e19abca31e1811a0/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L866)  to get the `resized_input_tensor` which is created in [`create_module_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/422ac2c400534ef15c0cd289e19abca31e1811a0/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L290) as follows ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/422ac2c400534ef15c0cd289e19abca31e1811a0/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L305)):

```
resized_input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, height, width, 3])
```

Thus, the data is expected to look something like:

```
{
  "image": [
    [
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
        # ... (num entries = height)
    ],
    # (num entries = width)
  ]
}
```

Of course, this is a fairly inefficient way to encode an image (floats as ASCII). It's not terrible if the expected image size is small (often it's 200 x 200). What would be better is if the authors of the example allowed the model to be exported with a call to `add_jpeg_decoding` as the entry point to the model, which would allow you to send the data as you currently are trying to do so.